# Binary Search in C plus plus

Tags: c++, binary-search

the code when executes creates an infinite loop.

What is wrong with this code :-(

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
 int arr[10]={1,20,30,75,90,189,253,302,304,455}, start=0, end=9, item, mid, i;
 cin>>item;
 mid=(start+end)/2;
 while(arr[mid]!=item){
     mid=(start+end)/2;
     if(item>mid){
         start=mid+1;
     }
     else if(item<mid){
         end=mid-1;
     }
 }
 cout<<"Found at location : "<<mid<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: One place to look at `if(item >mid){` `mid is the index.  You want to compare the value at that index.

Comment: okay I edited the code but still not working

Comment: `item` is a value inside the array, not the index. `start`, `mid` and `end` are indices of the array, not the values of the array. Replace `item > mid` by `item > arr[mid]`. Replace `item < mid` by `item < arr[mid]`

Comment: You're not handling the case where the element isn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your actual question: "What is wrong with this code?", see comments below:

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[10] = {1,20,30,75,90,189,253,302,304,455}, start=0, end=9, item, mid, i;
    cin >> item;
    mid = (start+end) / 2;
 
    // You function loops indefinitely...  The first place to look is here, at 
    // the test for your loop.
    // One thing is quite plain here :  You will loop indefinitely if the item you 
    // search for is not in the list.
    //
    // You should also stop looping when your search interval has reduced to 
    // nothingness, as this indicates the item is not found...
    //
    while (arr[mid] != item) {  // <-- BUG

    // try this instead: 
    while (start <= end) {  // loop while interval size is >= 1 ('end' is inclusive)
        const int mid = (start + end) / 2;

        // Check for search success here:
        if (arr[mid] == item)            
        {
            cout << "Found at location : " << mid << endl;

            return 1;    // we're done! exit loop
        }

        if (item > mid) { // <-- BUG!!!

        // should be

        if (arr[mid] < item)
            start = mid + 1;
        else
            end = mid - 1;
     }
     cout << "Not found." << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great Explanation !!! , Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
   int arr[10]={1,20,30,75,90,189,253,302,304,455}, start=0, end=9, 
   item, mid, i;
   cin>>item;
   bool found = true;
   mid=(start+end)/2;
   while(arr[mid]!=item ){
       mid=(start+end)/2;
       if(item > **arr[mid]**){
          start=mid+1;
       }
       else if(item< **arr[mid]**){
          end=mid-1;
       }

       if ( start > end ){ // termination condition
          found = false; break;
       } 
   }
 
   if ( found ) std::cout<<"Item found at: "<<mid<<std::endl;
   else std::cout<<"Item not found."<<std::endl;
}
```

See the changes between ** in the if checks inside the loop. It works now.

EDIT: Added a termination condition if the element is NOT found in the array. Your original code was looping infinitely because your conditions were wrong. The corrections in ** fixed the condition when the searched for element was actually inside the array. And now the termination condition takes care of the last case of infinite loop as well.

Comment: When does the function return if the value searched for is not in the list?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy That's for the OP to figure out, no? The question is about what's wrong with his code, not what's wrong with his understanding of binary search.

Comment: The question starts by "the code when executes creates an infinite loop.", not by "the code does not find my value".  If it's up to the OP to figure out the answer to the question he's asking, what is the point of this entire website?  :)

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Edited the code. Thanks for the heads up.